# Visual Studio 2010 breakpoints consistantly not being hit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-debugging

I have an issue with Visual Studio 2010 and an ASP.NET 2.0 project.

I have searched StackOverflow for a possible solution to my problem, but even though there are alot of articles related to the Visual Studio debugger, none specifically solve my issue.

Every time I start debugging, Visual Studio tells me that "The breakpoint will currently not be hit. The source code is different from the original version.". In the past when I got this problem, I could solve it by doing a Clean Solution. Or if that didn't work, I could always restart Visual Studio or my machine and the problem would be gone. This, however, doesn't work anymore. The solution cleans and I can rebuild, but the debugger still complains about the source.

I found that if I delete the folder "root" in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files", the problem is temporarily gone but only the next time I start the debugger, and only for the breakpoints that are currently set in the project. All breakpoints I add when the debugger is running are also not being hit due to the source/original difference.

I don't know how to solve this issue permanently because I don't want to delete that folder every time I have to start a debug session.

I also have a few ASP.NET 4.0 projects that debug just fine.

I use Windows 7 Enterprise (x64).

If someone has a suggestion I would very much appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
Right click solution.
Click "Property"
Go to: "Common Properties" -> "Project Dependency"
Select your "project" from drop down list
Check every item in list of "Depends on"
Click "OK"

Now Open **"Task Manager"**
And kill all worker process i.e. **"w3wp"** in case of iis7
Or Kill all **"WebDev.WebServer40.exe"** process

Now run your application.

Comment: Hi Deepak, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the dependencies are already set correctly.